# How to remove index.php and picture.php from Piwigo?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, configuration

```
https://example.com/index.php/categories
```

On url index.php it does not look good. How can I remove index.php from url?

```
https://example.com/picture.php?/246/category/red-color-women-shoes
```

`"picture.php?"` - want to remove for friendly url
`/246/` - Not sure what it is.
`/category/` - I think it should be category name but shows "category"

Piwigo is open source photo gallery software for the web
https://piwigo.org/

```
https://example.com/index.php/categories
https://example.com/picture.php?/246/category/red-color-women-shoes

$conf['question_mark_in_urls'] = false;
$conf['php_extension_in_urls'] = false; // this does not work
$conf['category_url_style'] = 'id-name';
$conf['picture_url_style'] = 'file';
```

Url should be

```
https://example.com/categories
```

and

```
https://example.com/category-name/red-color-women-shoes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#TURN ON REWRITES
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#THEN OPTIONALLY MAKE IT www if they didnt enter it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Write index.any to /
RewriteRule ^index\.[a-z]{2,3}     /     [L,R=301]

#THEN REWRITE LOCATIONS
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/category/(.*)$    picture.php?id=$1&page_url=$2   [L]
#IF CATEGORY IS ALSO DYNAMIC THEN TRY THIS FOR REWRITE
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)$    picture.php?id=$1&category=$2&page_url=$3   [L]
```

If I understand your question right.. hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems you are very much close to the solution.